# Any reason to use toString() method explicitly to print an object in Java

Tags: java, tostring

Just wondering if there is ever any reason to call `toString()` explicitly on an object to print it?

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // Assume toString() method is overriden in this class
System.out.println(obj);

System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

I obviously use the first approach, but one of my co-workers argues that I should put back that `obj.toString()`! I feel `toString()` is just redundant and not using it actually reduces the chances of `NPE`!

Am I missing something or do people have any reason to use `toString()` explicitly?

Comment: No, you're not missing something.  This is basically just an issue of taste.

Comment: No you don't have to use `toString()` explicitely.`print()` will call `String.valueOf(obj)` which will return "null" if `obj` is null or `obj.toString()`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If obj is null the second call will generate an NPE as you pointed out. As @Louis said, provided obj is not null, they're basically the same thing.

I would prefere to override toString() if I want to customize the literal rapresentation of MyClass, calling it WITHOUT the .toString() method to avoid the risk of NPE.

Answer (score 8):

`System.out` is an instance of `PrintStream`. If you call `println()` you will be calling this code:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

So it's just converting to a `String` anyway, although using `String.valueOf`. The difference is that `String.valueOf(null)` is `"null"` and just calls `toString()` on the object anyway if it's not `null`. But calling `toString()` on `null` causes a `NullPointerException` for sure.

So, use the former. It's simpler and handles `null`.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO do not use *`toString()`* explicitly, it could cause null pointer exception